how to make a row in a matrix only go as long as the first number?
so i have this exercise on matrixes which needs to be done with two dimensional arrays. the first part was that you have n, which goes from 1 to 9. for each row, you need to output the muliplication table of that first number. so basically:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18
3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27

and so on until 9.
this part i solved the following way:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] column = new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 }, { 6 }, { 7 }, { 8 }, { 9 } };
        int[][] row = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } };
        int[][] result = new int[column.length][row[0].length];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row[0].length; j++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < column[0].length; n++) {
                    result[i][j] += column[i][n] * row[n][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Teilaufgabe a: " + "\r\n");
        for (int[] rowResult : result) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowResult));
        }

    }

}

now my problem lies in the 2nd part of the exercise, where each line needs to be as long as the number of row[0], basically creating a stair structure.
it should look like this:

1
2, 4
3, 6, 9
4, 8, 12, 16

and so on
how can i make this happen? ive been struggling real hard with the implementation of it, it must have sth to do with the loop but ive been trying around a week to figure this out, so all help is greatly appreciated!!
critique on my already working code is also appreciated, since one of my friends said in a comment that its weird that im using 3 for loops for this issue
i tried changing things within my third for loop but couldnt quite figure that out. my other idea was creating a 2nd "int[][] result2" and have it run in its own 4th loop, but i couldnt figure out the parameters for the loop to be doing what i wanted it to do, so i scrapped it.

You'll only need two loops here. Create a new array of the needed length within the loop
int[][] result = new int[9][];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = new int[i+1];
    for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
        result[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
    }
}

for (int[] rowResult : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowResult));
}


Another way you can do it is using streams. It still results in a two dimensional result.
int[][] column = new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, 
                               { 5 }, { 6 }, { 7 }, { 8 },
                               { 9 } };
int results[][] = new int[column.length][];


for each column entry, stream a range of int's, limiting that stream to the number of columns.
then map the column values (1,2,3... column length) to a product of column number and column values
and put in an array which is also assigned to the appropriate row in results

for (int[] col : column) {
    int c = col[0];
    results[c-1]= IntStream.rangeClosed(1, c).limit(c).map(i->i*c).toArray();
}
for(int[] rows : results) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows));
}

prints
[1]
[2, 4]
[3, 6, 9]
[4, 8, 12, 16]
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36]
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
[8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64]
[9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]

